# File Transfer / Write Binary Data to TCP Socket Connection in C / C++ on Unix

Tags: c, sockets, file-transfer, fread

I‘m working on a File Transfer Program: Client writes the Binary Data to the Server over TCP Sockets.

When trying to write all the binary bytes to the socket, I don‘t know how to stop when all bytes of the Transfer File are read. The program simply does NOT stop and keeps on writing the binary bytes to the socket.

What’s the error ?

Code Example:

```
printf("[+] Starting File Transfer\n");
char buffer[BLOCK_BUFSIZE];

size_t contentLength = 0, rc;
FILE *absFile = fopen(absolutePath, "rb");

while ((rc = fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, absFile))) {
    if (rc == -1) {
        perror("Receive {-1}");
        break;
    }
    write(socket_fd, &buffer, rc); // Write to Socket
    memset(&buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
    contentLength += rc;
    printf("[+] Writing Buffer to Socket {%zu}\n", contentLength);
}
fclose(absFile);
printf("[+] Finished Writing Buffer\n");
```

Any ideas, suggestions, websites, inspirations ... ?

Thx ∆

Comment: Unrelated: Check the return code from `write(socket_fd, &buffer, rc);` as well. You might not write everything you wanted to write for a number of reasons.

Comment: Can you use [`sendfile()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sendfile.2.html) on your platform? This is often the most efficient approach since it just does it all for you in the kernel.

Comment: The memset is just a waste of cycles:(

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for your response, That‘s a good approach which I‘ll check out. But do you know, what the error is of my Program ?

Comment: My C is rusty (got busted the other day for consulting the 1978 edition of K&R when looking up behaviour added in C89) but I'm not seeing the error. What you have should loop only until `fread` returns zero, no bytes read. The check for errors won't work. `fread` returns 0 for no more data and error. When the loop exits, check `ferror` or `feof` to see what happened. That shouldn't interfere with the loop.

Comment: I could be misremembering what happens if you call `fread` after hitting EOF, so give `while ((rc = fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, absFile)) < BLOCK_BUFSIZE)` a shot to only read until you don't manage to read a full buffer. Don't forget to write that last bit of data into the socket if the reading didn't halt because of an error.